# Whitespace on application screen

Tags: android, xml

I have a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#C9D1D4" >
```

By default there is a keyboard on screen when application start, but after character input there is a white space on place of keyboard. This can you see on screenshot.
[image]

Why isn't there background texture?

Comment: This is weird. Is this on a device or on an emulator?

Comment: @Vucko: This is a Gigaset tablet.

Comment: First time I see something like this. Does the same thing happen on a different device?

Comment: Can you share the code you used to display the keyboard?

Comment: You shouldn't need to have two XML namespaces defined - just one in the root view of your hierarchy.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell : When editText gets focus on app start keyboard is opening.I use only TextChangedListener on this input field.

Comment: @M.Palsich : How should I do this exactly?

Comment: The outermost tag that wraps all of the others (i.e. a ViewGroup such as FrameLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc. with the views arranged appropriately with tags nested inside this layout) should be the only tab with an xmlns attribute.